# Transparent text with solid shadow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the effect mentioned in the title:

[image: desired effect]

I used the following code:

```css
.contact-txt h1 {
 color: transparent;
 font-size: 60px;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #00d44a;
}
```

But what I get is a green text:

[image: see here]

Is there a way to have a transparent text with a solid shadow as in the first picture?

Comment: does this solved your problem?

Comment: no, unfortunately mix-blend-mode is not working for some reason on my html structure.

Comment: that's the other guy's solution, does my solution work?

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow @ClaudioSinopoli , If any answer helps you [vote it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow), If the answer is what you looking for mark it as [Correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for the future readers. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel I tried your solution as well but it's not working in my case. Maybe it's something related to the html structure of my page...

Comment: @Daniel I'm new here so I don't know if it's allowed to provide my url to have a look.

Comment: ok, if you have a live link

Comment: solved. see below. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supported by modern browsers with the exception of Edge, you have mix-blend-mode.

This allows you to set a blend-mode , hard-light, that handles gray as if it was transparent. You then set the color of text to gray, and you got your effect:

```css
.test {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #00d44a;
  mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
}

.bkg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">DIRECTOR</div>
<div class="bkg"></div>
```

Comment: Good one, in Chrome the shadow looks semi-transparent to me.

Comment: Not working in my case :/ I can't understand why, since the snippet is rendering perfectly the effect I need.

Comment: Works!!! The problem was related to my html structure... I was adding the mix-blend-mode to the wrong class :/

Comment: Just to integrate, I was using the following to be sure the effect to be rendered on different browsers:
`-webkit-mix-blend-mode: hard-light;`
`-moz-mix-blend-mode: hard-light;`
`-o-mix-blend-mode: hard-light;`
`-ms-mix-blend-mode: hard-light;`
`mix-blend-mode: hard-light;`

Comment: As far as I know, IE / Edge don't support this feature, even prefixed ... So -ms-mix-blend-mode is useless.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to have two div stack together, if you only use one with transparent, the shadow is not blocked by text.

Using two could achieve this effect

> ### -webkit-background-clip: text
>
> (**currently supported in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, and being implemented in Firefox**) is the text value for background-clip. When used along with the proprietary -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; feature, this allows you to clip background images to the shape of the element's text, making for some nice effects. This is not an official standard, but has been implemented across multiple browsers, as it is popular, and used fairly widely by developers. When used in this context, both of the properties would require a -webkit- vendor prefix, even for Non-Webkit/Chrome-based browsers:
>
> ```
> .text-clip {
>   -webkit-background-clip: text;
>   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
> }
> ```
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Advanced_box_effects#-webkit-background-clip_text

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://www.cameraegg.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-140mm-f-3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-sample-images-1.jpg);
  font-size: 70pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

div.shadow {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 7px 7px red;
}

div.text {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="shadow">DIRECTOR</div>
<div class="text">DIRECTOR</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but has limited cross-browser support.

Comment: @webbm thanks for the tip, I tested, on few browser(FF, iOS safari, Chrome), seems ok. I checked Mozilla reference, yes It is not a standard yet (currently supported in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, and being implemented in Firefox)

Comment: Note that `-webkit-background-clip: text;` works in Firefox 49.0 and later. That is not a typo - the `-webkit` prefix works in Firefox!

Comment: @Golphy yep, thanks for the detail as I said (currently supported in Chrome, Safari, and Opera, and being implemented in Firefox)